# Retrieving original stylesheet CSS property value in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know that the **original** css value from the style sheet can be assigned using: $('#id').css('property', ''); but is there a way to retrieve the value without changing the property in the object? Note that may be different from retrieving the **current** value because it may have changed from the style sheet value.

---

Possible "solutions" (untested)

```
var originalTopPos = $("#testPic").css("top");
....
$("#testPic").animate({"top": originalTopPos + "px"},"slow");
```

I'm using many images though... so it is a bit more complicated than that.

---

(I want to animate it from the current to original value, not just jump from one value to the other)

```
var currentTopPos = $("#testPic").css("top");
var originalTopPos = $("#testPic").css("top", "").css("top");
$("#testPic").css("top", currentTopPos + "px")
$("#testPic").animate({"top": originalTopPos + "px"},"slow");
```

Comment: can you rephrase your question. .css('backgroundColor') will return the value of the background color of the selected element. Nothing changes.

Comment: You could always store the first value in a variable, modify the element, and then refer back to that variable later on.

Comment: matchew: first I mentioned .css('backgroundColor','')  - notice the extra argument. That is supposed to change the element back to the original stylesheet value. Without the second argument it returns the current value and that might be different to the original stylesheet value.

Comment: Wex: yeah that was my first "solution" but I'm using several images which have different #ids and it is hard to access different variables based on different #ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer....

```
$(this).attr("customAttributeName", $(this).position().top);
```

then you can recall it with:

```
$(this).attr("customAttributeName");
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this depends on whether you want to push the current value or the original. Since you say original, the surest way is to (if you're using JQuery) create a script within `$(document).ready(...)` that executes first and stores values for everything to variables.

The second way is to do `$(this).css("style-name","")` (the null argument resets to default).

If you are simply pushing the current value, you can do the similar thing with the variables. `myVar = $(this).css("style-name")` returns the current attribute value. Do not do `var myVar = ...`. Its just `myVar`. My browser yelled at me about that.

Answer (score 0):

This will return 'none'

```
<div id="test" style="display:none;"></div>

var property = $('#test').css('display');
alert(property);
```

Comment: I think that would return the current value rather than the original.... though "$('#id').css('property', '')" resets the property to the original.

Comment: Does this help ? `var offset = $("#id").offset(); 
alert(offset.top);`

Comment: I can't test it at the moment but I think that returns the current value which is not necessarily the original value.

Comment: what do you mean by the original value? the one in the style sheet? can't you just set that as a var at the beginning of your script? before the `top` element is modified? `var my_var = $("#id").css('top')`, before anything involving `$id` ?

Comment: Yep I mean the one in the style sheet. I've edited the original post with your solution. But I've got many images that will be moving around so I'll have a few variables to store and access which seems messy. I'd rather use one JQuery statement to access the style sheet value.

Comment: With many images it would be like this: var my_var1 = $("#id1").css('top'); var my_var2 = $("#id2").css('top'); var my_var3 = $("#id3").css('top')..... I wonder how #id3 for example could automatically access my_var3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

is this what your looking for?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        newColor = $('#id').css('color');
        $('#newid').css('color',newColor);
        $('#id').css('color','green');
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #id{color:red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="id"><h1>Boom!</h1></div>
<div id="newid"><h1>Boom!</h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to use "animate" (see my original post) and have many images (many id's).... the problem is linking the original style sheet value to each id... ideally I would be able to make a custom property for each image (e.g. the property "originalTop"). Then I could do: $(this).animate({"top": $(this).css("originalTop") + "px"},"slow");

Answer (score -2):

Assuming I understand the question, you just want something like object.style.property, no need for jQuery.

Comment: How would I retrieve the "top" property from the image #testPic? (in jquery I can reset it using $("#testPic").css('top', ""); but I want to leave the image alone)